# Pentaho Data Integration commercial costs + azure hosting

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

I did some Google searches but could not find any clear answer. How much does PDI/kettle costs for commercial usage? Is it potentially free? Can it be hosted in Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your work amount. If you are looking for a very limited amount of usage, then Pentaho Community Edition would be better, since its free. But for Pentaho Enterprise Edition, you need to pay for the licence and stuff. Do not know much on the exact pricing and stuff.

But since you are looking only for Kettle, i would suggest to go with [CE edition](http://community.pentaho.com/)
. Hope it helps :)

Comment: What are the limitations of the Community Edition of Kettle/PID versus the Enterprise Edition?

Comment: @csetzkorn there is not much of difference b/w CE and EE edition. EE will have regular support from the pentaho community rather than CE. But it would not make any difference in terms of using the Kettle features. it would all be the same. You can look at this link for more: http://forums.pentaho.com/archive/index.php/t-70983.html

Comment: Thanks. Can I use the CE version commercially though?

Comment: @cs0815 PDI CE is Apache license, so yes, you can use it commercially

Answer (score 7):

The company I work for was recently given a quote for the Pentaho EE licence. I'm from the uk so the price is in pounds. We were offered a quote of £30,000 a year and told it is usually £50,000 a year.

Needless to say, we settled with CE.

Comment: yeah that's exactly the problem. Have you had any issues with CE (only from a PID/kettle point of view)?

Comment: I haven't needed to get too involved with kettle as of yet, mainly using the report designer myself. But haven't encountered anything game breaking, or anything to warrant the price of EE.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is probably the only pricing info you can find on the interwebs.

Answer (score 3):

There are two flavors of Pentaho: a limited free version (Community Edition), and a professional version (Enterprise Edition). 
The Community Edition Kettle ETL (Extract, Transform and Load) tool is open-source and quite powerful, but the free version of the Business Analytics tool is not as versatile. You can find both here: http://community.pentaho.com/

The Enterprise Edition's price will vary depending on your planned use, primarily the number of cores you want to run it on. I can't give exact numbers, but as of December 2014 it's the most afforable of the professional BI platforms, probably about 10% of the cost of Microstrategy. Might still be out of reach of most small to medium businesses, though.

Comment: Thanks. I am not interested in the whole Pentaho BI solution but just in PID. Do you think you can license it separately?

Comment: I assume you mean PDI (aka Pentaho Data Integration). If ETL is all you need to do, the free community edition should be more than enough for that need. There are a vast number of connectors, allowing for a really wide set of data sources. Best way to figure out if it works for you is to get the free tool and try it out!